# concurrent/very fast php session requests pile up when using php sessions

Tags: php, session

I am using php sessions and would like to use a session variable to prevent requests from hitting the same script until the first once finishes. I need to do this on a per user basis.

Is my only option to create a database table that tracks if it is possible to run a query? It seems sessions wait (unless session_write_close() is called). session_write_close won't work in my case.

I want to do this:

Here is the basic logic

```
  if (!$this->session->userdata('sales_report_running'))
  {
        $this->session->set_userdata('sales_report_running', TRUE);

        //Do expensive query

        $this->session->set_userdata('sales_report_running', FALSE);

  }
```

Comment: Nope. Wrong and unreliable way of doing it. What you need is a queue. When a request to do the "expensive query" comes, put it in a queue. Execute the queue in order, as many tasks at a time as you can handle. Poll the server or _push_ notifications to the clients when their task is completed.

Comment: The idea I have doesn't work anyway because loading of the other requests is basically blocked from while it waits for the previous request(s) to complete. I like the idea of a queue, but if the page won't load until the other request is completed it is kind of already like a queue.

Comment: Yeah, now think of the resources you waste while waiting (thread/process, RAM).

Comment: Could you give an example of how to implement a queue in php? This needs to work on a basic php WAMP/LAMP/MAMP stack without any external programs or processes. (I have people install this on their own server and they wouldn't necessarily have access to install a separate application)

Comment: Well, knowing the request-based nature of HTTP there's no way of doing it without a daemon or at least a cron job. And what you need is to decouple the HTTP part from the resource consuming process.

Comment: The query can take anywheres from less than a second up to 5-10 seconds. Do you have any ideas at an application level to prevent lots of queries waiting in queue? I can think of a couple frontend changes...but as you know that can easily be circumvented.